# Delta PLC DVP14ss2 communication Problem with Co-Trust E-10 series servo driver (data-type problem)

Tags: plc

I have adjusted the resolution to 10,000 of E-10 series co-trust servo driver (if we write 10,000 to the given position parameter using the given software for setting parameters, it rotates by 360 degrees). The parameter is P290 = H122. The given software by cotrust is  "Magic Works Tuner". However, when I write the value 1 using DVP14ss2 on the same address, it completes 6.5536 rotations "6.5536*360 degree" (position= 65536, 10,000 means 1 rotation). I am using the following command for writing position:

```
MODWR K2 H122 K1
```

K2 is the driver's address. H122 is the hex equivalent address of the given position parameter (p290). K1 is value 1 that I am writing. In fact, it should rotate by 360 degrees, if I write 10,000. But, it goes to position 65536 (6.5536 circles) by given value K1 through PLC using **RTU Communication position control mode**. What could be the **problem**? Is it a **data-type** problem? If i write position vale, **K10000**, it should complete one rotation (360 degrees) according to given gear ratio.

Comment: I don't know if that's the case, I was reading the manual and for hexadecimal they always put it in 4 digits... Have you try `H0122`? Another thing, can you see the value written in the driver? And if you write K2 instead of K1, what happens?

Comment: @dwpessoa. Thanks for your response. Yes, I tried H0122 which is treated as the same H122. There is no problem in addressing it. If I write K2, it will go to position 131072 (65536*2). So, 1 implies 65536, 2 implies 2*65536, and so on...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it is sending data in 2 Words (32 bits), K1 (value = 1) was making all the bits low of the lower word as low (L'0x0000') and making the lowest bit of the higher word high (H'0x0001'). In Hex its value becomes "H00010000". Hence, `2^16 = 65536` was written on the motor driver's address. So, to resolve the issue, the following implementation is successful.

```
MOV K0 D104
MOV K10000 D105 #D104 represent lower word, D105 represent higher word (32 bit value)
```

#10000 is the resolution of the motor according to the adjusted gear ratio. So, the overall value is 10000 stored in a 32-bit format in D104 and D105. The value stored in D104 is written on Driver's parameters address H122 (parameter 290 is given position) and the motor rotates by 360 degrees.

```
MODRW K2 H10 H122 D104 K2
```